# Do Steam coupons stack?

Tags: steam

With all the coupons [Steam has at the moment](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/steam-item-giveaway-trading-thread), do they stack?

<sub>And I don't mean 2x 50% = free, I mean mathematically correct as in 100% - (100% - 50%)² = 100% - 25% = 75% total discount.</sub>

Comment: Actually, mathematically, (if the coupons worked that way) it would be 75% off. Like in department store clearance sales: take 50% off, then 50% off again. So `$100 * 50% = $50 off`; `$50 * 50% = $25 off`; `$50 off + $25 off = $75 off`.

Comment: @Krazer precisely, leaving you with 25% of the original price. (I admit I wrote it down a bit sloppy, sorry)

Comment: Tis okay~ I read "of" as "off." :P

Comment: @Krazer that would be a horrible deal: "Sir, I see you have a second 50% coupon, so you only get 25% off!":P

Comment: So true. I must still not be awake xD.

Comment: Had this question myself, +1.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler "Oh dear, you have _three_ 50% coupons. Good thing it's discount period!"

Comment: @badp :D "No, you can't bribe me with your fourth one to claim I have seen only one - I already get 50% employee discount, you think I'm fool?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's [one coupon per item](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4210-YIPC-0275), and most don't apply until after the sale is over.  The ones that do apply now are "golden" and say otherwise.

However, if an item goes on sale and you have a coupon that is valid during those dates, you can stack these two discounts, assuming it's not explicitly forbidden by the terms of the sale.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this help article](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4210-YIPC-0275):

> You can use one coupon per item.

Although it doesn't give a limit per transaction, so I can't vouch that you can buy two items and apply a coupon to each.

Comment: Thanks, I think one coupon per item works (otherwise one could simply buy one item at a time to circumvent this anyway). I don't know about bundles though

Comment: At first I would think a bundle counts as an `item`, but on second thought it's likely considered literally: `a bundle of items`.